# My xfce panel is not at top after a debian upgrade, how can I solve this?

Tags: xfce, panel

I have upgraded my debian from jessie to buster, and my XFCE panel is not anymore at the top of the screen. Here is a screenshot of the top left corner:

[image]

As my upgrade broke many things, I have reinstalled my system from scratch, keeping only /home. The result is the same. I have tried to put the panel vertical and back to horizontal, nothing changed. I don't see anything in the configuration of the panel that can help me.

How can I solve this problem please, without falling back to original settings like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109438/how-to-go-back-to-original-top-panel-in-debian-mint-xfce)?

Comment: Have you tried moving it around with your mouse?

Comment: Ho my ! It just works, thank you. I tried but not at the right place. It works either at the very left or right side.